# Which Sprite Kit node defines the shouldRasterize property?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I read in documentation that there is a shouldRasterize property, but it doesn't mention where. I look at SKNode, SKSpriteNode, SKCropNode and can't find it.

Comment: Have you searched it in Apple Developer site? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/index.php?Search=shouldrasterize+spritekit

Answer (score 2):

It's defined on [`SKEffectNode`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEffectNode/shouldRasterize).

Comment: also SKScene which is a subclass of SKEffectNode